# Performing multiple operations in one SSH command

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, shutdown

I have a command,

```
# ssh -t computer.A 'command'
```

to execute a simple command on computer.A remotely over SSH.

To add to this, I want to execute a command on computer.B through computer.A. 
In my head it would look like this:

```
# ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B 'shutdown -p now' shutdown -p now'
```

This command would first shutdown computer.B and then computer.A, but it only shuts down computer.B, and ignores the command to shutdown computer.A.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to escape your quotes and separate the two commands from each other.

```
ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B \\'shutdown -p now\\'; shutdown -p now'
```

If you wanted the second shutdown on computer.A only to run if the first was successful, replace the `;` with `&&`.

You could also alternate the quotes like so:

```
ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B "shutdown -p now"; shutdown -p now'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first command be: `ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B '\''shutdown -p now'\''; shutdown -p now'`

Comment: That will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine being on computer A. You want to shutdown computer B. How do you do this?

You type,

```
ssh -t computer.B 'shutdown -p now'
```

Now you want to execute *that* command ("ssh -t computer.B...") on *your* computer. You need to quote it, but in the command there are already two quotes, so you need to *escape* them:

```
ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B \'shutdown -p now\''
```

and actually you want to execute two commands, so you need to add it inside the outer quotes:

```
ssh -t computer.A 'ssh -t computer.B \'shutdown -p now\'; shutdown -p now'
```

If you want to **iterate** this by connecting to your computer from outside, just rinse and repeat:

- first stage, escape all quotes *and all slashes*, so `\` becomes `\\` and `'` becomes `\'`. Which means that `\'` becomes `\\\'`:

  ```
  ssh -t computer.A \'ssh -t computer.B \\\'shutdown -p now\\\'; shutdown -p now\'
  ```
- second stage: enclose in quotes, add the shutdown command and prepend the ssh instruction:

  ```
  ssh -t mycomputer 'ssh -t computer.A \'ssh -t computer.B \\\'shutdown -p now\\\'; shutdown -p now\'; shutdown -p now'
  ```